# Is Google adsense breaking my menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, adsense

I've noticed a annoying bug.

When you navigate on my website, **[the menu (on top right) acts normally]**.

But as soon as you go to a page with a Google AdSense ad, **the menu appears completely exploded for 1 to 5 seconds** (this means that we can see all the submenus).

If you have a slow connection, you'll notice even more than the others.

What's causing this? Is this the advertisement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because youre doing the hiding in JS id assume... try adding `style="display: none;` to the hidden elements so they are hidden before the menu is built with js.

Comment: ok i hope this won't break the behaviour of the menu, will test it ASAP. Thanks

Comment: Its possible, but the issue with the problem is the time it takes the page to load sp that jquery can do its thing. if you limit the number of scripts you include you can speed this up as well though there will likely be some delay.