# Does display: none affects SEO on a navigation menu?

Tags: jquery, css, seo, menu

i want to know if using display:none (via CSS) on a menu will affect SEO (make it less efficient) than using only display:none (via jQuery)

Thank you

Comment: You should take this question to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the problem is that hiding the menu with JS is when there is an ad to display, the menu isn't hidden the time that the ad is loaded ( 1 to 5 seconds) like here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444940/is-google-adsense-breaking-my-menu-displaying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a **usability** *AND* **SEO** perspective, you shouldn't hide elements that are crucial to the webpage - i.e. the primary navigation.

If your requirement is to first hide it and show based on some user action, I would use jQuery to do the hiding.

EDIT: I understand your problem that the navigation might be visible for a brief second before jQuery "kicks in", however this can be solved using inline javascript instead of the usual $(document).load() event.

```
<ul id="menu"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none'; // OR
    $("#menu").hide();
</script>
```

**Hope this helps,**

**Marko**

Comment: the problem is that hiding the menu with JS is when there is an ad to display, the menu isn't hidden the time that the ad is loaded ( 1 to 5 seconds) like here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444940/is-google-adsense-breaking-my-menu-displaying

Comment: If we use $("#menu").hide(); On page load , the html element will be visible then only javascript hides the menu . If the connection is slow , first menu will be shown on page loading